# Django Model TypeError many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django-models, django-tests

I'm getting this error while ruining the test TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use participants.set() instead.

I understand the error but I don't know how to implement the correct solution

```py
class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        url = reverse("index")
        self.response = self.client.get(url)
        User.objects.create_user(
            username="testuser",
            email="test@meetup.com",
            name="adivhaho",
            bio="test bio",
            password="testpassword",
        )
        Event.objects.create(
            name="test event",
            description="test description",
            created=datetime.datetime.now(),
            updated=datetime.datetime.now(),
            date=datetime.datetime.now(),
            participants=User.objects.get(username="testuser"), #! this is not correct
            
        
        )
        Submission.objects.create(
            details="test details",
            event=Event.objects.get(name="test event"),
            participant=User.objects.get(username="testuser"),
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign a user to a many-to-many field directly. You need to use the `add()` method.

```py
Event.objects.create(
    name="test event",
    description="test description",
    created=datetime.datetime.now(),
    updated=datetime.datetime.now(),
    date=datetime.datetime.now(),
)

event = Event.objects.get(name="test event")
event.participants.add(User.objects.get(username="testuser"))
```